# Rename button disabled for github repository

Tags: github, repository, rename

Such a simple thing as renaming a GitHub repository via its settings page. Now the button labeled "Rename" is disabled when I try different new names. Any clue what is happening?

Comment: have you tried typing something different in the box?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I tried different valid names. Also tried with another repo, but same issue.

Comment: try clearing cache/cookies. it works fine for me. the button is disabled until you enter something different to its current name. If that doesn't fix it, you should probably ask Github.

Comment: Still the same problem... I'll contact GitHub then. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Solved. The issue was due to my browser not being supported. There was not errors nor alerts, so I could not figure this out at first. I could rename the repo using a different web browser.

Comment: Which browser and version were you using?

Comment: The one I had an issue with was chromium Version 22.0.1229.94

Comment: I had the same issue with Firefox 10